# cmake IMPORTED_LOCATION generator expression debug release

Tags: cmake

I have an imported library in `MyNameSpace::MyLib`. During the install I want to copy these libraries to the lib folder. Therefore I do

```
get_target_property(myprop MyNameSpace::MyLib IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE)
install(FILES ${myprop} DESTINATION lib)
```

But how can I select the correct `IMPORTED_LOCATION_**` with the correct ending. I know there is `MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_<CONFIG>`, but how can I use a generator expression to resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found it

```
install(FILES $<TARGET_FILE:MyNameSpace::MyLib> $<TARGET_SONAME_FILE:MyNameSpace::MyLib> DESTINATION lib)
```

See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#target-dependent-queries.

Comment: At least here this doesn't seem to work for `IMPORTED` libraries. CMake claims that "target ... is not an executable or library" even when `IMPORTED_LOCATION` is set.